# Drupal 7 - EntityFieldQuery - use with mysql FIELD(...) for custom order by

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

I'm quite to new to Drupal's db api, and I'm working with some legacy code. I am trying to order the nodes selected by my **EntityFieldQuery** with a custom list.

MYSQL equivalent:

```
...
ORDER BY FIELD(tid, '44', '47', '21', '3' '36');
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do it with EntityFieldQuery. I thought I could with [fieldOrderBy](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3afieldOrderBy/7)(...). And `propertyOrderBy(...,...)` fails.

Helps is quite appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use [propertyOrderBy](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3ApropertyOrderBy/7) by passing the full field expression as the column to order by. Like so:

```
$query->propertyOrderBy("FIELD(tid, '44', '47', '21', '3' '36')", "asc");
```

I know, though, that if Drupal determines that it should call [propertyQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3ApropertyQuery/7) this will fail, because it will want to append the base table to the sort column.

If this doesn't work, you might just build your own raw query to get the data you want.

Comment: I tried it but it fails, I´ll ended up doing something else outside the Database. Thanks anyway!